# Deploy VS2010 Extension (VSIX) and register new file extension on windows

Tags: visual-studio-2010, registry, vsix

I've created a VS2010 extension to manage a new type of project. I've created the VSIX file with the project and item templates inside, and everything works fine, i'm able to create a new project, syntax highlight, compile it, etc.

What i want to do now is to associate my files (.stadyn) to the VS2010, like a .cs file. I mean, give it an icon and open the VS2010 on a double-click.

Does anybody know how to deploy the extension and add those keys to windows registry?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to possibilities.

1. Create an installer for your extension which is doing all the stuff.
2. Add the file associations when the extensions first starts.

I would prefer option one, since then you can also uninstall your extension and unregister the file associations and may be do other cleanup stuff. Also you could do other stuff during the install.

**Edit:**

Deployment is documented in the MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff363239.aspx

Comment: I thought it, but i dont know how to deploy the vsix extension from the instaler. Any idea/sample?

Comment: as far as I know it would be enough to copy the files to C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Extensions but i am not sure, also a vsix is basicly a zip file so to install a extension Visual Studio copies the contents of the vsix to that folder

Comment: exactly where the files go depends on what' in the VSIX eg item or project templates won't go in the same place. I think the installer could just "launch" the VSIX and rely on the shell to get VS to handle it.