# Set Icon on Myfiles with my extension and launch my software

Tags: c#, file, installation, file-association

I created a type of file for saving my software information that it has an extension like myfile.xxx
But after saving that file is unknown for windows. Anyway, I want to set an icon for files and open my software on a double-click.(Like Microsoft word, photoshop, etc.)

Also I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407561/deploy-vs2010-extension-vsix-and-register-new-file-extension-on-windows) question but it was not useful for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a few keys to the registry, if you don't want to do it through an installer:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\xxxfile]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xxx]
@="xxxfile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\xxxfile\DefaultIcon]
@="path_to_your_icon"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\xxxfile\shell]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\xxxfile\shell\open]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\xxxfile\shell\open\command]
@="command_to_run_on_double-click"
```

How to do this is another matter, most installer packages will have an option to do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your "file association" appropritely. Check out this question [Is there a Windows API to modify file type associations for an extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446879/is-there-a-windows-api-to-modify-file-type-associations-for-an-extension) and other related question for "file-association" tag.